# In a DataFrame, how could we get a list of indexes with 0's in specific columns?

Tags: python, database, pandas, numpy, dataframe

We have a large dataset that needs to be modified based on specific criteria.

Here is a sample of the data:

**Input**

```
   BL.DB  BL.KB  MI.RO  MI.RA  MI.XZ  MAY.BE
0      0      1      1      1      0       1
1      0      0      1      0      0       1
```

```
    SampleData1 = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,0]],columns = 
    ['BL.DB',
     'BL.KB',
     'MI.RO',
     'MI.RA',
     'MI.XZ'])
```

The fields of this data are all formatted 'family.member', and a family may have any number of members. We need to remove all rows of the dataframe which have all 0's for any family.

Simply put, we want to only keep rows of the data that contain at least one member of every family.

We have no reproducible code for this problem because we are unsure of where to start. 
We thought about using iterrows() but the documentation says:

```
#You should **never modify** something you are iterating over.
#This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the
#data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing
#to it will have no effect.
```

Other questions on S.O. do not quite solve our problem.

Here is what we want the SampleData to look like after we run it:

**Expected output**

```
    BL.DB  BL.KB  MI.RO  MI.RA  MI.XZ  MAY.BE
0      0      1      1      1      0       1
```

```
    SampleData1 = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,1,1,0]],columns = ['BL.DB',
    'BL.KB',
    'MI.RO',
    'MI.RA',
    'MI.XZ'])
```

Also, could you please explain why we should not modify a data we iterate over when we do that all the time with for loops, and what is the correct way to modify DataFrame's too, please?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Please break your question into input, expected output, output (and/or) error you're getting, reproducible codes you've tried etc.

Comment: `SampleData1.eq(1).any().astype(int)`?

Comment: @Quang Hoang, No, it works for the sample code but with more families in the fields it does not catch all the rows that have 0's for any individual family.

Comment: @LazyCoder did that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to group on families and retain rows where there is one or more member for all families in the row.

One way to do this is to transpose the original dataframe and then split the index on the period, taking the first element which is the family identifier.  The columns are the index values in the original dataframe.

We can then group on the families (`level=0`) and sum the number of members in each for every record (`df2.groupby(level=0).sum()`). No we retain the index values with more than one member in each family (`.gt(0).all()`).  We create a mask using these values, and apply it to a boolean index on the original dataframe to get the relevant rows.

```
df2 = SampleData1.T
df2.index = [idx.split('.')[0] for idx in df2.index]
# >>> df2
#     0  1
# BL  0  0
# BL  1  0
# MI  1  1
# MI  1  0
# MI  0  0

# >>> df2.groupby(level=0).sum()
#     0  1
# BL  1  0
# MI  2  1

mask = df2.groupby(level=0).sum().gt(0).all()

>>> SampleData1[mask]
   BL.DB  BL.KB  MI.RO  MI.RA  MI.XZ
0      0      1      1      1      0
```

Comment: Thanks, great solution!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to group along `axis=1`. For each row, check that all families (grouped on the column name before `'.'`) have at least one `1`, then slice by this Boolean Series to retain these rows.

```
m = df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('.').str[0], axis=1).any(1).all(1)
df[m]

#   BL.DB  BL.KB  MI.RO  MI.RA  MI.XZ  MAY.BE
#0      0      1      1      1      0       1
```

---

As an illustration, here's what grouping along `axis=1` looks like; it partitions the DataFrame by columns.

```
for idx, gp in df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('.').str[0], axis=1):
    print(idx, gp, '\n')
#BL    BL.DB  BL.KB
#0      0      1
#1      0      0 

#MAY    MAY.BE
#0       1
#1       1 

#MI    MI.RO  MI.RA  MI.XZ
#0      1      1      0
#1      1      0      0
```

Now it's rather straightforward to find the rows where **all** of these groups have **any** single non-zero column, by using those with `axis=1`.

Comment: I came up with solution identical to yours :)  +1

Answer (score 2):

Start from copying *df* and reformatting its columns into a MultiIndex:

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2.columns = df.columns.str.split(r'\.', expand=True)
```

The result is:

```
  BL    MI      
  DB KB RO RA XZ
0  0  1  1  1  0
1  0  0  1  0  0
```

To generate "family totals", i.e. sums of elements in rows over the top
(0) level of column index, run:

```
df2.groupby(level=[0], axis=1).sum()
```

The result is:

```
   BL  MI
0   1   2
1   0   1
```

But actually we want to count zeroes in each row of the above table,
so extend the above code to:

```
(df2.groupby(level=[0], axis=1).sum() == 0).astype(int).sum(axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
0    0
1    1
dtype: int64
```

meaning:

- row with index *0* has no "family zeroes",
- row with index *1* has one such zero (for one family).

And to print what we are looking for, run:

```
df[(df2.groupby(level=[0], axis=1).sum() == 0)\
   .astype(int).sum(axis=1) == 0]
```

i.e. print rows from *df*, with indices for which the count of
"family zeroes" in *df2* is zero.

Comment: The MultiIndex is a really good way to organize stuff like this!